# updateSelectizeInput does not take the most recent value

Tags: shiny

I have an app in which I need to copy the state of input fields to reactive-Values. I do that way seen in the example, where you can choose the title that a plot should have by selecting from a selectizeInput:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("title", "Title", choices = letters),
  plotOutput("po")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  title_reactive <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$title, {
    print("input$title changed")
    cat("input$title: ", isolate(input$title), "\n")
    cat("title_reactive: ", isolate(title_reactive()), "\n")
    title_reactive(input$title)
  })
  observe({
    print("title_reactive changed")
    cat("input$title: ", isolate(input$title), "\n")
    cat("title_reactive: ", isolate(title_reactive()), "\n")
    # if(identical(input$title, title_reactive())){
    #   return()
    # }
    updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "title", selected = title_reactive())
  })
  output$po <- renderPlot({
    print("render plot")
    cat("title_reactive: ", isolate(title_reactive()), "\n")
    Sys.sleep(2)
    ggplot(iris)+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length))+ggtitle(title_reactive())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works fine, expect if you change the selectize input before the plot has finished rendering. In this case, the updateSelectize seems to somehow not take the new value specified in `selected` but take the one it had before changing it. When you look at the logs, you see, that clearly something is odd:

```
[1] "title_reactive changed"
input$title:  g 
title_reactive:  g 
[1] "input$title changed"
input$title:  c 
title_reactive:  g
```

This is a part of the infinite loop. You see that at one point both values are "g" but somehow the updateSelectizeInput seems to recover the already overwritten value "c". A possible fix is to uncomment the if-statement.

However, in my real app I also update the choices, so I would prefer that the updateSelectizeInput takes the real (=most recent) value. Is there a way to do that?

Edit:

I thought more about the problem and this seems to be the cause (time goes from left to right, each line indicates R processes):

```
user changes input to "A" ---> reactive changed to "A" ---> R changes input to "A"
                              user changes input to "B" ---> reactive changed to "B" ---> R changes input to "B"
```

The problem is that the input is changed to "A" *after* the user has already changed it to "B". This causes an infinite loop.

This problem would not occure if `updateSelectizeInput` were faster than the user. The problem is that R waits until it has done all computations until it sends the information to change the input to the browser. Is there a way to force the customMessage to be sent out immeadiatly?

So `session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)` only does `private$inputMessageQueue$add(data)` but I need to have the message sent to the browser immeadiately.

Comment: `title_reactive` is set to `input$title`, so what is the interest of `updateSelectizeInput`?

Comment: I have a complex app where it is possible to reload the state of the app from save-points that where created in the past. Then there are a few checks that happen and choices of input$title that are excluded because not relevant anymore. I cannot rely on input$title in this case because if you do two updateSelectizeInputs in the same observe, then the first one is ignored. But this is bad if in the first one you changed the choices and in the second one you change the selection. So I need to copy the state to reactiveVal, where I have direct control and can manipulate them in a predictable way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up preventing the user from chaning the input while shiny is still busy:

```
  tags$script(HTML(
    '
$(document).on("shiny:busy", function() {
document.getElementById("title").selectize.disable();
});

$(document).on("shiny:idle", function() {
document.getElementById("title").selectize.enable();
});
      '
  ))
```

However, in case somebody knows a way to send out messages to the browser (like with `updateSelectizeInput`) without waiting until the R processes have terminated I would be happy!